# const can only be used in a .ts file react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
const ACCESS_TOKEN = 'access_token';

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.47.2
```

I am watching a tutorial video in which the expert get the value from the api and stored it inside the const ACCESS_TOKEN but when i am doing it in my code it gives me an error

> const can only be used in a .ts file react native

Please suggest.

Comment: in which file are you trying to store this value ?

Comment: @DragomirKolev SignInScreen.js

Comment: if it's a JS file you will need to use var instead of const or change your file extention to .ts from .js

Comment: Okay but am i able to carry this variable globally .. sorry i am a bit learner in this. i want to hold the access token and then move that to different screens .

Comment: Okay then, i think I know what you need to do. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: @DragomirKolev Okay . Thanks!

Answer (score 90):

The const is inside a class.  Move it outside the class and all will be ok.

Comment: What are the repercussions of doing it that way i.e. moving your const outside the class? I get compile error if I do that

Comment: @YuvalLevy because, functional expressions with type declarations aren't allowed in class methods. You can simply use `yourFunctionName = () => {//code}` instead of `const yourFunctionName = () => {//code}`

Comment: or just remove the const and keep it inside the class component.

Answer (score 20):

This error occurs when you use const, let, var keywords inside a class in javascript.
To set a property to a class, you do not use const, let or var keywords.

But you need to use const, var or let keywords to define variables inside a method of a class
example

```
class List extends React.Component{
     // But using const outside method and inside a class will give error
     /* const accessToken = ACCESS_TOKEN  is wrong syntax */
   render() {
     const accessToken = ACCESS_TOKEN;   // will not give error

}
```

Answer (score 5):

The const is inside a class, move it outside of the class and the error will disappear.

Answer (score 2):

In your SignInScreen.js file do:

```
export const ACCESS_TOKEN = "token";
```

In your other js file you want to use it you will have to do something like this:

```
import * as globalConst from 'path/to/SignInScreen';

var token = globalConst.ACCESS_TOKEN;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: export const ACCESS_TOKEN = "token"; 

not working both showing the same error .ts file

Comment: what happens if you change the statement to export var

Comment: Do you just get a IDE error or can you not compile the code at all ? What happens in webpack when you compile with export const ?

Comment: Have you tried changing the extension of the file from .js to .ts ?

Comment: It should convert your file to typescript from javascript. It will not. Also you can change it back after if it doesn't work.

Comment: OMG ! how stupid i am . sorry form my end i made a mistake .. i am using const inside the class and that's why it is not working. now it's working with the .js extension

Comment: but it's good to have this error today i learnt that we can also use .ts in place of .js :P Thanks for your help buddy

Comment: Haha, no problem. Sometimes you need to ask the question and go through it with someone to fix it yourself :). Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `this.state` in your constructor of class component in `react.js` file. Assign a property to `this.statement` and it will not give you any error. For example:

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state= {
         anyProperty : itsValue;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

had same problem, for me the slution was that I forgot to close a '}'.