# Why constant is not allowed in class component in .js file using React Native? And what is the best way to refer to child component?

Tags: javascript, react-native, constants, this

I have encountered a problem when I'm trying to define constant functions and numbers inside a class component in React Native. After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917365/const-can-only-be-used-in-a-ts-file-react-native/50392303), I recognized that keywords such as `var`, `constant` and `let` is not allowed inside class, and I have to either move the constant outside of the class or inside `render()` (or an another way is to change the file extension from .ts to .js)

This makes me really confused because

1. Normally in other programming languages, defining variables or constants inside class is often allowed
2. I want to define a constant component, e.g. `<Card>` (by `constant Card = () => {}`) inside the class component and then use it in `render()`. But as I have to remove `constant`, I will have to refer to the component `Card` inside `render()` as `<this.Card>`, which makes the code look a little bit unaesthetic (as I also need to refer to other components this way as well)

So I have questions here:

1. Why should `var`, `constant` and `let` not allowed in Javascript by design? And is there a "good" way to do it in Javascript?
2. Is there any way that I can still refer to the components without the keyword `this`, but still maintain the logical structure of the code? (because I think that defining a child component inside the parent component will make the code looks more logical, instead of throwing its definition outside the parent component scope)

I would be appreciated for all your help

Comment: can i know why you need const inside the class?

Comment: @SavinderSingh Yes, as I have stated above, for example, I have a class component named ```<Game>```, and I need to have a const component named ```<Card>``` inside it, as card is part of the game. The problem is that I can't have const inside class so if I remove ```const```, then I have to refer to ```<Card>``` as ```<this.Card>``` instead; otherwise, if I move the definition of ```<Card>``` outside the class of ```<Game>``` and keep the keyword ```const```, then my code will not show clearly the logical fact that card is part of the game

Comment: Why not put the definition of `Card` inside the render, but before the return? Then in the return statement you can render `Card` without needing `this`.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden It is an option that I considered, but I don't know if the ```<Card>``` should be inside ```render()``` "logically" - I mean, ```render()``` function should include less definition and focus on rendering. But your suggestion is the best option I've known so far. Can I ask: from your point of view, is there a better way of representing such relationships logically in React Native code? And do you know an answer to my first question? I appreciate your help