# The 'const' modifier can only be used in TypeScript files

Tags: javascript, typescript, paypal, e-commerce

I am following instructions from react-paypal-js to add Paypal buttons to JS React webpage.

https://github.com/paypal/react-paypal-js

I get the following error with

```
  const initialOptions = {
    "client-id": "AYTn1khGKSYyaSuXGWKl8OAPtqwV3v-EVlMHWaG3LsENDs6OvnVkXz0QLKjZ8fSnTU9PKYM1LDWJC0CT",
    currency: "USD",
    intent: "capture",
    "data-client-token": "abc123xyz==",
  };
```

and in Render() `<PayPalScriptProvider options={initialOptions}>`

If I use the const variable, the error is `The 'const' modifier can only be used in TypeScript files.`

If I remove the const variable, I get the error `'initialOptions' is not defined` in `<PayPalScriptProvider options={initialOptions}>`

How do I fix this without switching to typescript?
And why does this error occur

Comment: Are you using a class-based component? If so, your answer is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917365/const-can-only-be-used-in-a-ts-file-react-native